# Do you need some detailed stock market knowledge to understand the plot/story of Scam 1992?

Tags: scam-1992

I'm planning to watch [Scam 1992](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12392504/), but I know nothing about stock market and not much interested in it.

But since it's a top rated series, I'm planning to watch it. I feel there's something unique in it. Maybe something meaningful message in the end.

So my question is, do you need detailed stock market knowledge, like what is stock and stock market to understand the story or plot (the scam itself to be precise)? Is the stock market core of this series? I mean is it heavily dependent on stock market and investment?

Comment: I haven't seen it so I don't know for certain, but usually any 'technical' aspect of any movie is spoon-fed to the audience [to varying degrees of accuracy] so they don't need to already understand that aspect beforehand. The technique is often called exposition or info-dump, depending on how much is explained & in what sort of quantities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the stock market core of this series? I mean is it heavily dependent on stock market and investment?

Yes, this show is about one of the biggest scams happened in Indian stock market. So, the stock market is the core theme of the show.

> do you need detailed stock market knowledge, like what is stock and stock market to understand the story or plot (the scam itself to be precise)?

I possess really no knowledge about the stock markets and yet I didn't feel lost while watching this series. The production team did a good job explaining some basic terms like what is the Bull and Bear, some of the rules at that time, etc. As you go forward in the series, the terms will be explained to you.

So, I don't think you have to have deep knowledge about the stock market in order to enjoy this show.